# Regex Pattern for fullname

Tags: php, regex

I'm having trouble creating a regex pattern for my php that a full name with a max of 40 characters and only one space (that is required).

What I have now.

```
/^[a-zA-Z- ]{1, 40}$/
```

Comment: The space is optional or required?

Comment: Not every name has only one space in it. Some names have two, some have hyphens in them.

Comment: what about trying `/^[a-zA-Z ]{0,40}$/` . If I've understood correctly, you are specifying an exact length and not a max or a range.

Comment: Welcome to SO: please don't edit your question once it's posted with changes to your code from what you glean in the conversation. It reduces the usefulness of the comments and answers that follow. Thanks!

Comment: *"I'm having trouble creating a regex pattern for my php that a full name"* ... I'm not surprised : http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @ShawnMehan I am indeed new here, apologies for any confusion caused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This regex would check for a 40 character string that contains only alpha characters and one space.

```
(?=^.{0,40}$)^[a-zA-Z-]+\s[a-zA-Z-]+$
```

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/CIhJgs/2/
PHP Demo: https://eval.in/802889

<s>This could be done without a regex though. Consider:</s>

1. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php
2. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

Comment: You left out the hyphens from the pattern. Names with hyphens will no longer match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Oh, missed that thanks. (actually looking at history that was added in mid question).